# Printing multiline C++ style comments in shell script

Tags: shell, cygwin, echo

How can you print C++ style multiline comments in the shell script? I want to be able to add a multiline comment automatically to files using a shell script. I've been tinkering around but I can't find a way to add `/**` in a string. I am using Cygwin on Windows 7.

Here are my attempts so far:

```
comment="/**"
echo $comment

comment='/**'
echo $comment    

comment="\/**"
echo $comment
```

But so far, the only result I've been getting with this method is:

```
/bin /cygdrive /Cygwin.bat /Cygwin.ico /Cygwin-Terminal.ico /dev /etc /home /lib /opt /proc /sbin /srv /tmp /usr /var

comment="\/\*\*"
echo $comment
```

Prints out `\/\*\*...`

So how can I echo `/**` (or `**/` for that matter)?

Comment: `*` is handled specially by the shell (expand the filenames from the current directory). If you need to escape some character it's the `\*`.

Comment: You need to quote the *usage* of the variable (`echo "$comment"`) to prevent the shell from expanding the glob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
comment='/**'
echo "$comment"
```

Always quote variables that could contain glob patterns (otherwise they'll be expanded, as you noticed).

Since in general you don't know whether that's going to be the case, always quote them unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: I'd sooner write "Always quote variables". And the quotes on the assignment aren't technically necessary.

Comment: Good point. I'd rather leave the quotes in the assignment though, regardless of whether they're necessary.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said "technically". I prefer to leave them off because they can (shockingly) cause a problem in very rare cases but that's not something I push on anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some assignment examples:

```
comment=\/\*\*
comment="/**"
comment=/**
comment='/**'
```

For all of the above `echo "$comment"` prints the same output: `/**`